# Java Scanner not working as expected

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read a file into my java program where the first row in the txt file is an int and everything after is a long.  The issue that I am having is every single line of code in the while loop is calling `s.nextint()` and `s.nextLong()` (at least when I put a watch on them in Eclipse).  I want them only to increment through the text file where I call them.

Firstly, what am I doing wrong because it was my understanding they should only increment when called and not on every line of code, and is there a better way to do this? I was thinking if need be I could just load them all in as a single type to an array and cast later, but this wouldn't be what I consider reasonable. I feel this should be fairly simple but I am overlooking something.

Also lets say there are 10 numbers in the text file and go 1-10.  I understand that it is a waste to save a small number as an int but just go with it.

```
public static long[] readfile()
{
  int row = 1;
  Scanner s = null;
  long[] nums = null;
  try {   
    s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader( new FileReader("text.txt")));   
    while (s.hasNext()) {   
      if(row == 1){
        nums = new long[s.nextInt()];
        row++;
      }
      else {
        nums[row - 2] = s.nextLong();
        row++;
      }
    }
  }
  catch (FileNotFoundException e) {   
    e.printStackTrace();   
  }    
  finally {   
    if (s != null) {   
      s.close();   
    }   
  }   
  return nums;
}
```

Comment: Use `hasNextInt` with `nextInt`, similarly `hasNextLong`

Comment: Would I replace the row == 1 with s.hasNextInt(). is that what you mean?

Comment: To be honest, your question is unclear to me. If I run your program (after the fix of the problem Shar1er80 mentioned), then everything works fine. Since you introduced an example, can you what result you get and what you expect?

Comment: Yeah I mentioned in my self answer that I believe it was one of 2 things. a problem with scanners or eclipse on my end.  It would come to random errors if I stepped through but would work fine if i just ran it plainly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue i stated was having something to do with an eclipse error.  If i just run the code or set a breakpoint after the readfile in the main my code works as expected, but when I stepped through values weren't being assigned right by eclipse i'm guessing.  Interesting issue.  I would like to see exactly what was causing it.  Seems very unlikely but isn't that coding? nothing goes as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer something like this:

```
do 
{   
  if(row == 1){
    nums = new long[s.nextInt()];
    row++;
  }
  else 
  {
    nums[row] = s.nextLong();
    row++;
  }
}while(s.hasNextLong());
```

I didn't try to compile or debug it; holler if you need further help. (It assumes there will be an integer atop the file, as you said would be the case. You should probably add code to guard against that not happening.)

Comment: still doing the same thing.  Each line nextint and next long are assigned so when next int is called it is getting 4 rather than 1 (using my sample numbers from above.

Answer (score 0):

You're code is throwing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.  You're trying to use `row` for two purposes which throws off your array indexing.  By the time we get to the `else` block, row is equal to 2 and you're trying to apply row to an array from 0 - 9 (10 longs for example).

You should trying initializing your array after checking `hasNextInt()` then get your `long` numbers after checking `hasNextLong()`

Code Sample (text.txt has 10 numbers [1234567890]):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    long[] longs = readfile();

    if (longs != null) {
        for (long l : longs) {
            System.out.println(l);
        }
    }
}

public static long[] readfile() {
    int row = 0;
    Scanner s = null;
    long[] nums = null;
    try {
        s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("text.txt")));
        if (s.hasNextInt()) {
            nums = new long[s.nextInt()];
        }
        while (s.hasNextLong()) {
            nums[row] = s.nextLong();
            row++;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (s != null) {
            s.close();
        }
    }
    return nums;
}
```

Results:

```
1234567890
1234567890
1234567890
1234567890
1234567890
1234567890
1234567890
1234567890
1234567890
1234567890
```

Comment: I noticed this right before you had posted and was going to edit my code.  Thanks for catching it though regardless.

Comment: @jnics23 Then what issues are you still having?

Comment: I found the issue kind of.  I created an answer for it. Basically it was probably eclipse messing up.  I don't know the specifics that caused it but I found a work around.

Answer (score 0):

I've generally found that Scanners behave oddly when attempting to read multiple types. I'd create a separate Scanner for each type that you'll be reading.

Comment: Good to know for future reference.  Maybe that is what caused my issue I Posted in my answer.